# How do I correctly iterate through symbols as keys for creating a hash table?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In short: (gethash 'PARIS *pandemic-hash-table*) is returning nil, despite 'PARIS being a key in the table; this seems to be related to quoting/evaluation of symbols during the hash-table creation in some way but I can't figure it out.

I'm playing with a graph search (testing for the shortest route between cities in the board game Pandemic; just for fun - trying to find optimal research lab placement in a way more sophisticated than 'has the most edges'). I'm using a hash table to hold the route data (nodes and edges), and, needed to input the data as a preliminary:

```
(defvar *nodes* '('San-Francisco 'Chicago 'Atlanta 'Washington 'Montreal 'New-York 'Madrid 'Paris 'London 'Essen 'Milan 'St-Petersburg))

(defvar *edges* '(('Chicago 'St-Petersburg)
                  ('San-Francisco 'Atlanta 'Montreal)
                  ('Chicago 'Washington)
                  ('Atlanta 'Montreal 'New-York)
                  ('Chicago 'Washington 'New-York)
                  ('Montreal 'Washington 'Madrid 'London)
                  ('New-York 'London 'Paris)
                  ('Madrid 'Essen 'London 'Milan)
                  ('Madrid 'Essen 'London 'New-York)
                  ('London 'Paris 'Milan 'St-Petersburg)
                  ('Paris 'Essen)
                  ('Essen 'Chicago)))

(defvar *pandemic-node-hash* (make-hash-table))

(loop for node in *nodes*
      for edges in *edges*
      do (setf (gethash node *pandemic-node-hash*) edges))
```

If I look at the resulting hash table:

```
CL-USER> (loop for key being the hash-keys of *pandemic-node-hash*
               do (print key))

'SAN-FRANCISCO 
... ;other keys removed for brevity
'PARIS  
NIL
```

So it's making the table (and the edges show up similarly), but, `(gethash 'PARIS *pandemic-node-hash*)` returns `nil`. If I then add another 'PARIS node directly `(setf (gethash 'paris *pandemic-node-hash*) 'somevalue)`, and check the keys, I get:

```
(loop for key being the hash-keys of *pandemic-node-hash*
               do (print key))

'other keys
'PARIS
PARIS 
NIL
```

So, the problem has *something* to do with the evaluation of the symbols (`'PARIS` and friends) in the initial hash table creation loop, but I can't quite figure out what's going on or how to do that correctly. I'm guessing `node` evaluates to the *un*-evaluated symbol, passing that to gethash ... but what's the right way? Surely not (eval node)? Backtick the list, with commas in front of the symbols? (ugh).

Comment: `(defvar *nodes* '('San-Francisco 'Chicago ;;...))` -- why quote both the list and the symbols? Just do `(defvar *nodes* '(San-Francisco Chicago ;;...))`.

Comment: Well sure, it's easy when you say it! I somehow thought you needed to quote symbols to pass them, even though I wouldn't write ('3 '4 '5), etc. Thanks.

Comment: You need to quote symbols to pass literal symbols -> such that a symbol does not get evaluated. But you have already symbols in the list. If you call `(foo (first *nodes*))`, Lisp will evaluate `(first *nodes*)`, but will not evaluate again the result of that.

Comment: Inside `'( ... )`, none of the enclosed data will be evaluated and thus none will need to be quoted to prevent evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember: `'foo` is the short form for `(quote foo)`. It's a list with two elements: the symbol `CL:QUOTE` and the symbol `FOO`.

```
 (defun show-it (arg)
   (print (list arg (type-of arg)))
   (values))
```

Above is a smaller helper function for this answer.

```
CL-USER 37 > (show-it 'hamburg)

(HAMBURG SYMBOL)
```

Above shows that the function sees the symbol `hamburg` and not the value of a variable `hamburg`.

**Not**

```
CL-USER 38 > (show-it '('hamburg))

(((QUOTE HAMBURG)) CONS)
```

Above: the function sees a nested list, with a list, which has `quote` as a symbol.

Note: `((quote hamburg))` can be written shorter as`('hamburg)`.

```
CL-USER 39 > (show-it (first '('hamburg)))

((QUOTE HAMBURG) CONS)
```

Above: if we get the first element, we get the list with the `quote` symbol.

**Better**

```
CL-USER 40 > (show-it '(hamburg))

((HAMBURG) CONS)
```

Above provides a list with one symbol, the symbol `hamburg`.

```
CL-USER 41 > (show-it (first '(hamburg)))

(HAMBURG SYMBOL)
```

Above gets the first element, which is the symbol `hamburg`.

**Evaluation**

Make sure that you understand evaluation in Lisp. `quote` blocks evaluation for the whole quoted expression and on all levels of those. Thus it makes no sense to quote contents inside a quoted list.

When passing arguments in a function call, then quoting is used to prevent lists and symbols to be evaluated. Thus `quote` creates literal data: literal symbols, literal lists, literal vectors, etc.

Thus quoting is a mechanism of code, not of data.

Code:

```
(first '(hamburg)) vs. (first (hamburg))

getting the first element of a literal list vs.
getting the first element of the result
of calling the function `hamburg`.
```

Data:

```
(paris hamburg berlin rome)  vs. ('paris 'hamburg 'berlin 'rome) 

A list of city names vs. a list of city names,
each nested in a list (quote ...)
```

Thus:

`('paris 'hamburg 'berlin 'rome)` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
(dolist (node *nodes*)
  (dolist (edges *edges*)
    (setf (gethash node *pandemic-node-hash*) edges)))
```

But also you've double quoted your symbols (as someone else commented)

Why:

```
'(('Chicago 'St-Petersburg) ...)
```

when it should probably be just this (don't quote the list and each symbol)

```
'((Chicago St-Petersburg) ...)
```

You would see this if you evaluated: *edges*

Comment: Yes, removing the double quotes solved my issues! Regarding your suggestion: isn't that going to iterate each node through all edges (assigning finally the same 'last edge' as the value for each node)?

Comment: Your nested `do` loops do not do the same thing as OP's `loop` form. With `loop`, variables introduced by `for` are iterated in parallel. Consider: `(loop for x in '(a b c) for y in '(1 2 3) collecting (list x y))` --> `((A 1) (B 2) (C 3))` vs...

Comment: ... `(let ((result '())) (dolist (x '(a b c)) (dolist (y '(1 2 3)) (push (list x y) result))) (reverse result))` --> `((A 1) (A 2) (A 3) (B 1) (B 2) (B 3) (C 1) (C 2) (C 3))`